# How to get fixed buffer length?

Tags: c#, pointers, sizeof, fixed, unsafe

Is there a way to get the length of a fixed size buffer?

Something like:

```
public struct MyStruct
{
    public unsafe fixed byte buffer[100];

    public int foo()
    {
        return sizeof(buffer); // Compile error.
    }
}
```

Is there any way to accomplish something like this?

Comment: Why don't you define a constant like const int BUFFER_SIZE = 100, then use buffer[BUFFER_SIZE].  This runs quicker size the assignment is done by the compiler.

Comment: Because that would add some unwanted verbosity to my structs. My code would have a lot of structs like that. Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: It is a lot less code than to put a method foo in each structure.

Comment: But I wasn't going to create that foo method, I just wrote to clarify the things and concepts :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well [like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15774534/c-how-to-get-the-length-of-a-pointer-array) in C++, you have to keep size of built-in arrays. Same applies for fixed buffers in C#. This type is [comparable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13798264/4965962) to `inline_array`. This gives you benefits such as static code checking. They are a bit of a pain to work with as they aren't C#'s first class feature. So probably the best solution is to keep size as a part of struct. You will probably just have to deal with it or use a collection/C#'s `System.Array`. Maybe another solution would be to create fixed buffer as a seperate struct and then make it part of another stucts with other data.

Comment: Okay, considering this is the closer answer 'll accept. Unfortunatelly c# is showing itself very limited when deeper interop comes to play :/

Comment: "in C++, you have to keep size of built-in arrays" just isn't true.  `(sizeof array)/(sizeof *array)` works great on built-in arrays, including struct/class data members with array type.  Or you can use inference of non-type template parameters.  You linked to a discussion on finding the size of the dynamic memory range a pointer points to, which is not at all what is going on in the C# code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm answering like 6 years late but I did this. Apparently there's a property that contains the length of the fixed buffer! Here's a simple method to get it. You need to pass the MyStruct type and the name of the field:

```
    public static int GetFixedBufferSize(Type type, string field)
    {
        FieldInfo fi = type.GetField(field);
        object[] attrs = fi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(FixedBufferAttribute), false);
        if (attribs != null && attribs.Length != 0)
        {
            FixedBufferAttribute attr = (FixedBufferAttribute)attribs[0];
            Console.WriteLine($"{attr.ElementType.Name} {field}[{attr.Length}]");
            return attr.Length;
        };

        throw new Exception("Not a FixedBuffer");
    }
```

Hopefully this works for you, I tried it with your example and it worked!

Comment: Does this depend on reflection?  You're asking for a field according to its name as a runtime-variable string?  Surely that's not fast, so it's not something you'd want to use in normal code if you're using an `unsafe fixed` array for performance reasons.

Answer (score -4):

That's an array; you can just use `.Length`.

Comment: fixed size buffers isn't an array. Length  is a property of System.Array, therefore I can't access that :(

Comment: Maybe @MartinCostello, could you show me how I could use Marshal.SizeOf in a fixed buffer? Thanks.

Comment: You could try these:

`return Marshal.SizeOf(this);`
`return Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MyStruct));`
`return Marshal.SizeOf(buffer);`

Comment: None of that works in my case @MartinCostello. MyStruct would contain another types, SizeOf(typeof(MyStruct)) will return the marshal size of the entire struct and SizeOf(buffer) don't compile. SizeOf expects a Type.

Comment: `buffer` is a field, which is an object. Does the code even compile if you remove the `foo()` method? I think your field declaration is wrong.

Comment: @MartinCostello: No; it's just that `fixed` is weird.  I'm not sure if this is possible at all (!).  Play with http://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#f:s/K4Zwlgdg5gBAygTxAFwKYFsDcAobAHYAIwBswBjGFAJ2DORgFkE5ka7sBvbGHmAk8jGAQQAQwBmqGOLAAPVABMYhBGmXBxkqgG0AjAAZ9AXRzde/UhWFjJMSPXEB7RwAoAlGZ5dePmFVTIwFQQ6pqoVAB0ADKo0MgAFjg+AL7YqUA===

Comment: Maybe try using `[MarshalAs]`, rather than `fixed`. Then you won't need unsafe code. https://github.com/martincostello/sqllocaldb/blob/master/src/SqlLocalDb/LocalDbVersionInfo.cs#L48-L49